# Creating a co-occurrence matrix using r

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, rbind

I would like to build a co-occurance matrix for the following data(randomly generated):

```
         OTU1 OTU2 OTU3 OTU4 .... OTU598
patient1  0    1    1    0        1    
patient2  1    0    1    0        1 
.
.
.
patient143 1   0    1    1         1
```

I want to create a co-occurance matrix with three columns as follows: (one patient): 
Consider first otu and compare with all other OTUs. if two OTUs (eg: OTU1 and OTU2) have 1, then I would like to create a column called counts and put 1.

```
otu1    otu2    counts
OTU1    OTU2      0
OTU1    OTU3      0
OTU1    OTU4      0
OTU2    OTU1      0
OTU2    OTU3      1
```

So I tried the following code:

```
a <- apply(bin_OTU_tab,1,function(row_val) lapply(1:ncol(bin_OTU_tab), 
                                              function(i){ lapply(i:ncol(bin_OTU_tab),
                                                                  function(j){if(bin_OTU_tab[row_val,i] == 1&&bin_OTU_tab[row_val,j] == 1){return(1) }else{return(0)
                                                                    }})}))
```

Its in the matrix format. I want to change this matrix into dataframe and arrange as the desired output(as mentioned above). I hope rbind would work? But couldnt get it how to continue from here.
could anyone pls guide me in this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives a list of matrices, one for each patient:

```
# fake data
set.seed(47)
m = matrix(round(runif(15)), nrow = 3)
colnames(m) = paste0("OTU", 1:ncol(m))
m
#      OTU1 OTU2 OTU3 OTU4 OTU5
# [1,]    1    1    0    1    0
# [2,]    0    1    0    0    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    1

template = as.data.frame(t(combn(colnames(m), 2)))
names(template) = c("otu1", "otu2")
template$counts = 0

result = apply(m, 1, function(x) {
  ones = names(x)[x == 1]
  result = template
  result[result$otu1 %in% ones & result$otu2 %in% ones, "counts"] = 1 
  return(result)
})

result
# [[1]]
#    otu1 otu2 counts
# 1  OTU1 OTU2      1
# 2  OTU1 OTU3      0
# 3  OTU1 OTU4      1
# 4  OTU1 OTU5      0
# 5  OTU2 OTU3      0
# 6  OTU2 OTU4      1
# 7  OTU2 OTU5      0
# 8  OTU3 OTU4      0
# 9  OTU3 OTU5      0
# 10 OTU4 OTU5      0
# 
# [[2]]
#    otu1 otu2 counts
# 1  OTU1 OTU2      0
# 2  OTU1 OTU3      0
# 3  OTU1 OTU4      0
# 4  OTU1 OTU5      0
# 5  OTU2 OTU3      0
# 6  OTU2 OTU4      0
# 7  OTU2 OTU5      1
# 8  OTU3 OTU4      0
# 9  OTU3 OTU5      0
# 10 OTU4 OTU5      0
# 
# [[3]]
#    otu1 otu2 counts
# 1  OTU1 OTU2      1
# 2  OTU1 OTU3      1
# 3  OTU1 OTU4      1
# 4  OTU1 OTU5      1
# 5  OTU2 OTU3      1
# 6  OTU2 OTU4      1
# 7  OTU2 OTU5      1
# 8  OTU3 OTU4      1
# 9  OTU3 OTU5      1
# 10 OTU4 OTU5      1
```

Comment: Thank you for your time for giving this solution. Again, I am trying to output matrix for each patient. How do I get it?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were just working out the example for a single patient, not that you wanted each patient done individually. Don't have time to update now, sorry. I'll look again later

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am also trying different approach to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `base R`, then the following code may be something you want

```
l <- apply(m, 1, function(v) 
  setNames(data.frame(cbind(t(combn(colnames(m),2)),(M <- outer(v,v,"*"))[lower.tri(M)])), 
           c("otu1","otu2","counts")))
```

yielding

```
> l
$patient1
   otu1 otu2 counts
1  OTU1 OTU2      0
2  OTU1 OTU3      0
3  OTU1 OTU4      0
4  OTU1 OTU5      0
5  OTU2 OTU3      0
6  OTU2 OTU4      0
7  OTU2 OTU5      0
8  OTU3 OTU4      0
9  OTU3 OTU5      0
10 OTU4 OTU5      1

$patient2
   otu1 otu2 counts
1  OTU1 OTU2      0
2  OTU1 OTU3      0
3  OTU1 OTU4      0
4  OTU1 OTU5      0
5  OTU2 OTU3      0
6  OTU2 OTU4      0
7  OTU2 OTU5      0
8  OTU3 OTU4      0
9  OTU3 OTU5      0
10 OTU4 OTU5      0

$patient3
   otu1 otu2 counts
1  OTU1 OTU2      0
2  OTU1 OTU3      0
3  OTU1 OTU4      0
4  OTU1 OTU5      0
5  OTU2 OTU3      1
6  OTU2 OTU4      1
7  OTU2 OTU5      0
8  OTU3 OTU4      1
9  OTU3 OTU5      0
10 OTU4 OTU5      0

$patient4
   otu1 otu2 counts
1  OTU1 OTU2      1
2  OTU1 OTU3      1
3  OTU1 OTU4      0
4  OTU1 OTU5      0
5  OTU2 OTU3      1
6  OTU2 OTU4      0
7  OTU2 OTU5      0
8  OTU3 OTU4      0
9  OTU3 OTU5      0
10 OTU4 OTU5      0
```

**DATA**

```
m <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0), .Dim = 4:5, .Dimnames = list(c("patient1", "patient2", 
"patient3", "patient4"), c("OTU1", "OTU2", "OTU3", "OTU4", "OTU5"
)))
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. I tried it. But how to i get separate output for each patient?

Comment: @MSM now I know what you meant for `by patient`...please see my updated solution

Comment: @MSM sorry that I had a typo in my code, but now it is correct.